# How to set banner at top of list view dynamically

Tags: android

i want to set banner(image) at top of list view dynamically.i am calling list view data from webservices .i did this coding in my lazy adapter class but no banner being visible.i wana set banner like this.[image]

```
RelativeLayout layout1 = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
LayoutParams params2 = new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);              
image.setLayoutParams(params2);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
image.setMaxHeight(50);
image.setMaxWidth(50);
image.getPaddingTop();

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.topheader);
layout1.getPaddingTop();
layout1.addView(image);*/
```

i have banner image in my drawable.

---

this is my full code of lazy adpter class

```
package com.example.jsonparsing;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
int counter = 0;
Context mContext;
Activity a;

public LazyAdapter(Context context) {
this.mContext = context;
this.a = a;
}

public int getCount() {
System.out.println("Called..."+ Constants.vctrCategoryId.size());
return Constants.vctrCategoryId.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

System.out.println("Exception before..");
String strUrl = Constants.vctrImagePath.elementAt(counter).toString();// getting url of the images

System.out.println("Urls...." + strUrl);
URL url =null;
try {
url = new URL(strUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Constants.DownloadImage(strUrl);
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
//text.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

/* this coding i did for setting banner

/*RelativeLayout layout1 = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
LayoutParams params2 = new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
image.setLayoutParams(params2);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
image.setMaxHeight(50);
image.setMaxWidth(50);
image.getPaddingTop();

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.topheader);
layout1.getPaddingTop();
layout1.addView(image);*/


RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
//RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
//layout.setLayoutParams(params);
TextView text1 = new TextView(mContext);
text1.setText(Constants.vctrCategory.elementAt(counter).toString());
LayoutParams params1 = new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
text1.setLayoutParams(params1);
text1.setTextSize(20);
text1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
layout.addView(text1);




ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
img.setImageBitmap(resized);


layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.addView(img);
counter++;
return layout;
}

private void setContentView(ImageView image) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)  method of the [listView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) class

Comment: All you need to do is create your banner view by java code or by inflating an xml file then call `addHeaderView(bannerView)` on the instance of your `ListView` and pass the banner view as parameter... This method should be called from your activity not from the adapter...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution from the layout point of view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Guess it helps!

Comment: but i have no xml class m making list view dynamically(through coding)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
View headerView1 = ((LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_add, null, false);///this is your imageview 
list_view.addHeaderView(headerView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer by @kittu88. And if you want to add it dynamically, you can try this.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:od="@+id/banerLayout"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
```

Java code

```
LinearLayout bLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewbyId(R.id.banerLayout);
bLayout.addView(YOUR Image);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below ,

[image]

list_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/empty_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/header_layout_root"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    </TextView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sample_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sample_title"
            android:text="@string/sample_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sample_image">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Next go back to your ListActivity class and it’s time to put in the code to add the header to your list, place this just below the call to setContentView():

```
ListView lv = getListView();
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

ListWithHeader.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListWithHeader extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

        //add header to list
        ListView lv = getListView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
        lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

        //add some list items
        String listItems[] = {"List Item One", "List Item Two", "List Item Three", "List Item Four", "List Item Five"};
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
    }
}
```